# Design and implementation of an elegant Tufte-inspired two column presentation template?

Tags: beamer, templates, tufte, org-mode

I am interested in finding or creating a `beamer` template with the following characteristics:

1. left: a square (ish) figure, about 2/3 of the width
2. right: two or three statements, zero to four small figures, per slide on the right

I would like for the template to:

- simplify the process of creating a presentation
- be effective at conveying information

How can I accomplish these goals?

(I am interested in `Sweave` (or `org-mode`) integration, but I do not want that to distract the answers since I can implement this)

---

### Examples

Something with a `tufte-notes` style, as found in "[An Example of the Usage of the Tufte-Handout Style](http://tufte-latex.googlecode.com/files/sample-handout-3.5.0.pdf)", and seen below, would be very nice, but it is not clear how I can most effectively translate this style to `beamer`.

[image]

I am not a designer, but here is a mock-up (images from [NASA](http://starchild.gsfc.nasa.gov/))
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Your interest won't remain personal if you can describe your goal a little more clearly. A picture is n-thousand words on this Q&A site. Try and see our wizards in action!

Comment: Regarding the template layout, it seems that `columns` environment of `beamer` fits the bill. However, modifying the notes is a non-trivial task.

Comment: Wouldn't a simple `minipage` environment work: `\begin{minipage}{0.66\linewidth} <left content> \end{minipage}\hfill\begin{minipage}{0.33\linewidth) <right content> \end{minipage}`?

Comment: @PeterGrill I am interested in suggestions beyond how to divide each slide into columns, which is relatively trivial, although now I interested in looking into minipage.

Answer (score 10):

You mention org-mode, so I'll comment on that.  I gave my dissertation defense with a beamer presentation created with org-mode.  I had many cases where I had a picture on one side and then bulleted points on the other - it should be easy to have images instead of the bullets.  Below is an example, but if you want to look at the entire presentation, I've placed it here: http://ucolick.org/~cmalone/nolink/defense/

Here is an example

[image: screenshot]

with the accompanying org-mode code:

```
** What is an XRB?: Lightcurve
*** 4U 1728-34                                        :BMCOL:B_ignoreheading:
    :PROPERTIES:
    :BEAMER_env: ignoreheading
    :BEAMER_col: 0.7
    :END:
#+ATTR_LATEX: width=\textwidth                                                                                                                                                       
./quick3.png
#+BEGIN_LATEX                                                                                                                                                                        
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]                                                                                                                                    
      \node [yellow,xshift=10pt,yshift=20pt] at (current page.south west) {0};                                                                                                       
      \node [yellow,xshift=120pt,yshift=20pt] at (current page.south west) {$t$ (s)};                                                                                                
      \node [yellow,xshift=225pt,yshift=20pt] at (current page.south west) {32};                                                                                                     
      \node [yellow,xshift=200pt,yshift=100pt,rotate=90] (L) at (current page.south west) {Luminosity};                                                                              
      \draw [color=yellow,line width=2pt,->] (L.east) -- ++(0pt,50pt);                                                                                                               
    \end{tikzpicture}                                                                                                                                                                

#+END_LATEX                                                                                                                                                                          
*** 4U 1728-34                                           :BMCOL:B_alertblock:
    :PROPERTIES:
    :BEAMER_env: alertblock
    :BEAMER_col: 0.4
    :END:
- Buring mode sets $\tau_\text{dur.}$
- Inferred ignition column implies \alert{deflagration} $\rightarrow$ subsonic flow
\\
\tiny after \\ Strohmayer, T., et al., \textit{ApJL}, \textbf{469}, L9, (1996)
```

When exported to LaTeX (`C-c C-e l`), the relevant section in the resultant .tex file is:

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{What is an XRB?: Lightcurve}
\label{sec-1-3}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.7\textwidth}
%% 4U 1728-34                                                                                                                                                                        
\label{sec-1-3-1}

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./quick3.png}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
      \node [yellow,xshift=10pt,yshift=20pt] at (current page.south west) {0};
      \node [yellow,xshift=120pt,yshift=20pt] at (current page.south west) {$t$ (s)};
      \node [yellow,xshift=225pt,yshift=20pt] at (current page.south west) {32};
      \node [yellow,xshift=200pt,yshift=100pt,rotate=90] (L) at (current page.south west) {Luminosity};
      \draw [color=yellow,line width=2pt,->] (L.east) -- ++(0pt,50pt);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{alertblock}{4U 1728-34}
\label{sec-1-3-2}

\begin{itemize}
\item Buring mode sets $\tau_\text{dur.}$
\item Inferred ignition column implies \alert{deflagration} $\rightarrow$ subsonic flow
\end{itemize}
\\
\tiny after \\ Strohmayer, T., et al., \textit{ApJL}, \textbf{469}, L9, (1996)
\end{alertblock}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

This can most certainly be prettied-up, but perhaps it is a starting point for you.